# return program to a previous function and clear current function data(Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, input

The title might be a little unintuitive but I don't know how else to explain it.

So here's the deal I am desining an "application" for an assignment, and one of the requirements is that the app's UI be text based and works using a MVC pattern.

And one aspect I've been struggling to attain is to effectively "recede/go back" menus.

This is the best thing I've come up with:

```
public class Menu{
    Scanner read;

    public int MainMenu(){
        System.out.println("############# !!! Main Menu !!! #############\n");
        System.out.println("1) Shop");    //there's more options but I want to keep short and I only need one to demonstrate my troubles
        System.out.println("0) Quit");    //terminates the application

        int e = -1;
        while (e<0 || e>4){
            e = read.nextInt();
            if (e<0 || e>4)
                System.out.println("Wrong choice");
        }
        return e;   //this value goes to the controller that then redirects to fucntions such as the one we see bellow
    }

    public int ShopMenu(){
        System.out.println("############# !!! Shop Menu !!! #############\n");
        System.out.println("\nLogin with your acount. If you want to go back to the main menu type: -back.\n");

        System.out.println("Type your email: ");
        String email=read.next();     //this string is meant to be read in the Class that holds all the registred emails so it can verify it's validity, but that's a not a concern currently.
        switch (email){
            case "-back": MainMenu(); email=""; email = read.next() ; break;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

While I can go back to the Main Menu with this solution, **I think** the **email** string gets "used up" (as init's not longer empty and the user can't write any more on it) and the next time I select the shop menu I can't type another email and the program stops running.

My intention is for the once the ShopMenu function ends, the email string be cleared and the user can keep using it to insert other emails with the app terminating. All of this without obviously compromising the ability of going back previous menus.

**--EDIT--**

At the request of MarsAtomic, here's the program's output in it's current state:

> ####### !!! Main Menu !!!
>
> 1) Shop
>
> 0) Quit
>
> 1
>
> ####### !!! Shop Menu !!!
>
> Login with your acount. If you want to go back to the main menu type:
>   -back.
>
> Insira o email:
>
> -back
>
> ####### !!! Main Menu !!!
>
> 1) Shop
>
> 0) Quit
>
> 1
>
> -back
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What does "used up" mean? Describe what you see, not what you think is happening, because I'm pretty certain you aren't seeing what you think you're seeing. Better yet, to eliminate all doubt, run your program and copy and paste the output and edit it into your question.

Comment: I am trying to say the email string is no longer empty and I can't write/input anything on it anymore

Comment: OK, so here we go again... why do you think the email is "no longer empty?" Do you mean that when your program prompts for an email address the second time, it just prints the prompt and then exits without taking input? That's what the output seems to depict, and if that's true, then what is happening is not what you think is happening.

Comment: I am in the process of learning java, so I say I think that's what happening because that's the conclusion I reached based on my observations of the output and little experience and knowledge I have working with java. Anyway. Is there any advice or possible solution you or anyone can give me as to how I should deal with this issue?

Comment: @Mr.Maleiro That was kind of a rhetorical question. He's trying to help you examine your assumptions. Uncovering your assumptions is the first step when troubleshooting a problem of your own making. Examining them is the second step.

Answer (score 1):

While this question does not contain a question, I see the problem area.

Inside your switch statement

```
switch (email){
    case "-back": MainMenu(); email=""; email = read.next() ; break;
}
```

You call `MainMenu()`.

But you stated in a code comment that calling the correct method of `Menu` is the *controller's* responsibility. Here you are making it the responsibility of `Menu` to call the next `Menu` method.

Control flows as directed: while in the first go around of `ShopMenu()`, the -back case is invoked, calling `MainMenu()`, which returns an `int` to no one:

```
case "-back": MainMenu();
```

Then control goes to

```
email=""; email = read.next() ; break;
```

and then `ShopMenu()` finishes, returning 1 to (presumably) the controller:

```
return 1;
```

And one way or another '1' leads the controller to the end of its execution. Since it always returns 1, `ShopMenu()` will always lead to this outcome when it finishes.

---

Noting on the structure and stated goal, this code sure looks extremely C-like for a Java program.

If this is supposed to be MVC,

1) What part of the model is this `Menu` class? Is it the view? Shouldn't the view only be responsible for displaying? Should it also be responsible for input? Should it also be responsible for routing and input checking? Who is best to handle those responsibilities?

2) Why not additionally include at least the controller in what you supply here? We're lucky an identifiable problem was in what's provided, but we don't know what's calling these methods or when.

Java conventions will help you. Classes should generally be named after nouns, and methods should have a verb as the most important word. This isn't because "it's just proper", this is because it will help you think about what each part of your code represents, data or behavior.

Comment: The Menu class is the view yes. It looks like C because that's the only language I am somewhat confortable with (like I said I am learning Java). I fear pasting the Controller class would make this question way too long, I want to keep things simple.
So I should let the input be alwyas handled by the Controller class?
My main concern though is how can I allow the user to keep going back and forth between the Main Menu and Shop Menu whithout the program to stop running without the user's express comand.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, I think I managed to find the solution. Just had to use String Buffers and a recursive call in the ShopMenu function:

```
public void ShopMenu(){
        System.out.println("############# !!! Shop Menu !!! #############\n");
        System.out.println("\nLogin with your acount. If you want to go back to the main menu type: <b.\n");
        StringBuffer Semail = new StringBuffer();
        Semail.append(ler.next());
        String SMail = Semail.toString();
        if (SMail.equals("<b")) {
            email.delete(0, email.length());
            MainMenu();
            ShopMenu();
        }
}
```

Comment: This is still poorly structured code. Make sure you understand the answer that @pfdint posted. Good code has one entry point and (optimally) one exit point. Imagine trying to walk down a hallway. If you need to do something in a room, you enter, do what you need and go back into the hallway where you can move to the next room. You don't kick a hole in the wall to reach the next room. Code should not look like [this](https://www.npr.org/2011/11/11/142218444/bil-keanes-dotted-line-an-appreciation]) or [this](https://www.simplyhappyfoodie.com/instant-pot-spaghetti/).

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do in my code then? Because I am out of ideas...